# Eclipse hotkey doesn't work the same on my desktop & laptop

Tags: eclipse, ide, hotkeys, eclipse-indigo

I used the same (duplicated) eclipse on both of the machine. On my laptop i can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to access the quick fix menu. However, I have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num1</kbd> in order to access it on my desktop, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (with the '1' key near <kbd>Esc</kbd> key) hotkey doesn't work.

Do you have any idea why this happen and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it doesn't work. Maybe your key bindings aren't correct or your numpad and numrow have been switched around somehow.

Check your key binding. Go into **Window > Preferences > General > Keys** and search for **Quick Fix**. What does the Binding say? In the **Binding** text field, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and save.